# Neo4j 3.0 automate data loads

Tags: neo4j

How we can automate data loads in Neo4j 3.0, I am using LOAD CSV command for data loads, is there any way to schedule this like a batch job on windows platform?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use one of the [APOC procedures for Job Management](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures#job-management). For example:

```
CALL apoc.periodic.schedule('name', cypher-statement, repeat-time-in-seconds)
```

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/blob/master/src/main/java/apoc/periodic/Periodic.java), there is also a way to cancel a job by name (but it is not documented, for some reason):

```
CALL apoc.periodic.cancel('name')
```

The APOC plugin has to be installed on the neo4j server first.